# Keeping a count of words in a list without using any count method in python?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, count

I need to keep a count of words in the list that appear once in a list, and one list for words that appear twice without using any count method, I tried using a set but it removes only the duplicate not the original. Is there any way to keep the  words appearing once in one list and words that appear twice in another list?

the sample file is `text = ['Andy Fennimore Cooper\n', 'Peter, Paul, and Mary\n',
'Andy Gosling\n']`, so technically Andy, and Andy would be in one list, and the rest in the other.

Using dictionaries is not allowed :/

```
for word in text:
    clean = clean_up(word)
    for words in clean.split():
        clean2 = clean_up(words)
        l = clean_list.append(clean2)
        if clean2 not in clean_list:
            clean_list.append(clean2)
        print(clean_list)
```

Comment: If you're asking for homework, could you at least show us what you have tried?

Comment: I need to count except I don't want to count...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a silly problem removing key data structures or loops or whatever. Why not just program is C then? Tell your teacher to get a job...

Editorial aside, here is a solution:

```
>>> text = ['Andy Fennimore Cooper\n', 'Peter, Paul, and Mary\n','Andy Gosling\n']
>>> data=' '.join(e.strip('\n,.') for e in ''.join(text).split()).split()
>>> data
['Andy', 'Fennimore', 'Cooper', 'Peter', 'Paul', 'and', 'Mary', 'Andy', 'Gosling']
>>> [e for e in data if data.count(e)==1]
['Fennimore', 'Cooper', 'Peter', 'Paul', 'and', 'Mary', 'Gosling']
>>> list({e for e in data if data.count(e)==2})
['Andy']
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very bad, unPythonic way of doing things; but once you disallow Counter and dict, this is about all that's left.  (**Edit:** except for sets, *d'oh!*)

```
text = ['Andy Fennimore Cooper\n', 'Peter, Paul, and Mary\n', 'Andy Gosling\n']

once_words = []
more_than_once_words = []

for sentence in text:
    for word in sentence.split():
        if word in more_than_once_words:
            pass   # do nothing
        elif word in once_words:
            once_words.remove(word)
            more_than_once_words.append(word)
        else:
            once_words.append(word)
```

which results in

```
# once_words
['Fennimore', 'Cooper', 'Peter,', 'Paul,', 'and', 'Mary', 'Gosling']

# more_than_once_words
['Andy']
```

Comment: Thank You So much, it worked! :D it would have been easier if they had allowed us to use counter but yet again thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a set (I wouldn't use it either, if you're not allowed to use dictionaries), then you can use the set to keep track of what words you have 'seen'... and another one for the words that appear more than once. Eg:

```
seen = set()
duplicate = set()
```

Then, each time you get a word, test if it is on `seen`. If it is not, add it to `seen`. If it is in `seen`, add it to `duplicate`.

At the end, you'd have a set of `seen` words, containing *all* the words, and a `duplicate` set, with all those that appear more than once.

Then you only need to substract `duplicate` from `seen`, and the result is the words that have no duplicates (ie. the ones that appear only once).

This can also be implemented using only lists (which would be more honest to your homework, if a bit more laborious).

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
text = ['Andy Fennimore Cooper\n', 'Peter, Paul, and Mary\n', 'Andy Gosling\n']
one, two = [list(group) for key, group in groupby( sorted(((key, len(list(group))) for key, group in groupby( sorted(' '.join(text).split()))), key=itemgetter(1)), key=itemgetter(1))]
```